# Layout using <include> not stretching to match parent

Tags: android, android-layout

**main layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="32dp">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/sideBar"
            layout="@layout/layout_side_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            style="@style/ListItemText"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/sideBar"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:letterSpacing="-0.02"
            android:text="@string/xyz"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_desc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/sideBar"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_text_new"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_wait_icon"
            android:drawablePadding="14dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
            android:paddingStart="14dp"
            android:paddingTop="9dp"
            android:paddingEnd="14dp"
            android:paddingBottom="9dp"
            android:text="@string/abc"
            android:textColor="@color/primary"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**layout_side_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v_lineTop"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@color/green" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_number"
        style="@style/ListItemNumber"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_circle"
        tools:text="2" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v_lineBottom"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The view with id `v_lineBottom` in the `layout_side_bar` that is included in the `main layout` is invisible.

It only shows up if I give a specific height to the `v_lineBottom` view or to the included `android:id="@+id/sideBar"`

I am using the `main layout` as a `recycler view item`

Comment: inside layout_side_bar change the  android:layout_width="wrap_content" to  android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: @Raza It is the height that needs to stretch, and I am putting it as `match_parent ` already.

Comment: have you tried adding `padding_bottom` for `v_lineBottom` in `layout_side_bar.xml`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I am getting a view like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
android:clipToPadding="true"
android:paddingStart="16dp"
android:paddingEnd="32dp"
android:paddingRight="32dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp">

<include
    android:id="@+id/sideBar"
    layout="@layout/layout_side_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_name"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/sideBar"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:letterSpacing="-0.02"
    android:text="xys"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sideBar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_desc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/sideBar"

    android:drawablePadding="14dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
    android:paddingStart="14dp"
    android:paddingTop="9dp"
    android:paddingEnd="14dp"
    android:paddingBottom="9dp"
    android:text="@string/acre"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sideBar" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

and layout_side_bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical">

<View
    android:id="@+id/v_lineTop"
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="@color/blue" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_number"
    tools:text="2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/v_lineBottom"
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

can you show graphical representation of your view the way you want to achieve..

Comment: The graphical representation looks fine for me as well. But when the recycler view is rendered it doesn't show

Comment: i am not sure how you are populating your recyclerview and how does its adapter looks like